# How to fix uneven central heating and air?

Tags: hvac, central-heating, central-air

My central heating and air conditioning system does not heat my home evenly. Half of the house gets significantly warmer / cooler than the other half. I have tried adjusting the registers, but to no avail. It just seems like some of the vents blow harder than the others. What else would I need to adjust to make the house temperature more even?

Comment: It's difficult to answer this question without being on site. Without seeing how the system is setup and the layout of the home, it's difficult to answer accurately.

Comment: Is the thermostat in a central location?

Comment: I have a nest thermostat set up in the hallway.

Comment: I can't see your house from here, so I have no idea where the hallway is in relation to anything else.